# How to properly import an obj with all materials and textures using python?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, objects, import

I'm just about to import an `.obj` mesh to Blender and render it all by using a python script.

There are three files: `.obj`, `.mtl` and an image texture. I've checked the three files and confirmed they are in correct formats. I tried to manually import it to Blender and everything works well.

However when I use `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj` to import the mesh, even I set `filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl"`, the render result has no material as well as no texture applied.

**Q:** I would like to know whether I need to set any additional parameter to make it work...?